# Morse lemma via Moser's trick

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, morse-theory

In Abraham and Marsden's [Foundations of Mechanics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201408406), they prove Morse lemma via Moser's trick. They are able to reduce the proof so that it suffices to find a smooth family of vector fields $Z_t$ such that
$$\iota_{Z_t}\omega_t+(f-g)=0, \quad Z_t(0)=0,$$
where $f$ is the function under consideration in Morse lemma statement, $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}D^2f(0)(x,x)$ and $\omega_t=tdf+(1-t)dg$.

Now, the book says that it is "easy to see that $Z_t$ exists near $0$ by the nondegeneracy hypothesis", which I assume is referring to the non-degeneracy of the hessian $D^2f(0)$.

However, I can't see how it is easy to see that. For instance, $\omega_t(0)$ is $0$, so $Z_t(0)$ could be whatever we want and I see no way to easily reconcile this*. Furthermore, $\omega_t$ is a $1$-form and we want a $Z_t$ such that $\omega_t(Z_t)$ is some number. This gives a lot of redundancy for $Z_t$.

My question is: **How to build such $Z_t$?**

*This is quite different from the usage of Moser's trick on the symplectic situations (Darboux's theorem, say), where $\omega_t$, when constant on a region of interest (like the origin in this case), is usually non-degenerate (not to mention being a $2$-form, which is relevant for the next thing I am about to say)

---

For those not familiar, Morse lemma is as follows.

> Let $f:M \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $\mathrm{Hess}_p$ is non-degenerate and $f(p)=0$. Then there exists a chart $\phi$ around $p$ such that in local coordinates
>   $$f(x)=D^2f(0)(x,x).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $df(0) = 0$, given a vector $v$ we can write
$$
df(x)(v) = \big<G(x)v,x\big>,
$$
where
$$
G(x) = \int_0^1 \mathrm{Hess}\;f(sx)\;ds.
$$
In fact, 
$$
df(x)(v) = \int_0^1 \frac{d}{ds}df(sx)(v)\;ds = \int_0^1 D^2f(sx)(v,x)\;ds = \big<\big(\int_0^1\mathrm{Hess}\;f(sx)\;ds\big)v,x\big>.
$$
Thus, the equation
$$
i_{Z_t}\omega_t = g - f
$$
becomes
$$
\big<(tG(x) + (1 - t)H)Z_t(x),x\big> = \big<((1/2)H - G(x))x,x\big>
$$
where $H = \mathrm{Hess}\;f(0)$. Whence, it suffices to find $Z_t$ such that
$$
(tG(x) + (1 - t)H)Z_t(x) = ((1/2)H - G(x))x.
$$
Since $G(0) = H$, the operator $(tG(x) + (1 - t)H)$ is invertible for $x$ near $0$. Define
$$
Z_t(x) = (tG(x) + (1 - t)H)^{-1}((1/2)H - G(x))x
$$
in a neighbourhood of $0$.